# Outer apply and left join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using outer apply in sql server. can someone please explain if there is any performance difference between Outer Apply and Left Join ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really correct.

APPLY uses to join table with table-valued functions

JOIN we use to join two tables.

You may find more information in MSDN articles:

APPLY [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

JOIN [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: You answer is completely incorrect. APPLY in SQL Server 2008 can be used without table-valued functions and JOIN can be used to join subquerys or table expressions to tables. OUTER APPLY can be used as an alternative to LEFT JOIN with much better performance (not always).